# How can I update a column based on multiple values from multiple columns

Tags: sql

I am new to this. I want to update a column value where based on values of other columns. Example

```
Product   Make     Model         Years
Hyundai   Getz     1.4 Hatch/3D     5
Hyundai   Getz     1.4 Hatch/5D     5
Hyundai   Getz     1.6 Hatch/5D     7
Hyundai   Getz     1.6 Hatch/5D     7
```

I tried the following

```
UPDATE WARRANTY
SET  WARRANTY.period = 
    Case when PRODUCT.grpcode ='Hyundai'  
         and PRODUCT.Make =’Getz’  
         and PRODUCT.Model in ('1.4 Hatch/3D',1.4 Hatch/5D')
then 5
 end 
 end
```

Is this right?

Comment: You have no opening `'` on your 2nd `in`  Are the `getz` ones correct too?

Comment: Thanks for that forgot that when typing into this forum. Next set is the same first 2 conditions then model changes. Help with that too please

Comment: Are Warranty and Product 2 different tables? How are the joined / what is the relationship between them? Please show table definitions and some sample rows. What kind of SQL database are you using?

Comment: Yes they are 2 different tables

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: It may be worth constructing a warranty period table (from this query) to make the actual output, what warranty period does a car have more readable, i'm imagining the amount of case statements will become large and also somewhat inefficient each time, where you have the same warranty available for different cars.   In your example, a volvo 1.4 could also have 5 years warranty, so would argument be `hyundai or volvo` then if it changes volvo is no 4 years, code change.

Comment: You can't just use product columns in your update without als including the product table.

Comment: Show us sample data for both tables, and also _specify_ the expected result  - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

So depending on which SQL you are working on, the approach will change. Here's one way to approach this:

```
update warranty
set period = case  when PRODUCT.grpcode ='Hyundai'  
     and PRODUCT.Make ='Getz'  
     and PRODUCT.Model in ('1.4 Hatch/3D','1.4 Hatch/5D')
then 5
from product
where product.pid = warranty.pid
```

you will need a column in order to join the 2 tables. I am assuming you would have a column like that. This is an example of postgresql for Mysql you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE warranty
    INNER JOIN
product ON product.pid = warranty.pid 
SET 
period = case  when PRODUCT.grpcode ='Hyundai'  
     and PRODUCT.Make ='Getz'  
     and PRODUCT.Model in ('1.4 Hatch/3D','1.4 Hatch/5D')
then 5
```

you will have to do this for all the products and manually change values for all the products and run the code multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @Abdullah. I will give that a try

Comment: Hi @Abdullah I tried both options didn't work. I am using SQL Gives me an incorrect syntax error near 'from'